# Type=forking work fail on etc/systemd/system/redis.service on ubuntu16.04

Tags: redis, fork, systemd, notify

my /etc/systemd/system/redis.service is

```
# /etc/systemd/system/redis.service
[Unit]
Description=Redis Server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=redis
Group=redis
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown
Restart=always
Type=notify
#Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

work fine.

But when I change Type from "notify" to the web suggestion "forking"
I got the error and cannot restart or stop the redis.server

```
$systemctl restart redis
Job for redis.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status redis.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We’d need to see your `redis.conf` file to be sure, but according to [this default configuration file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/4.0/redis.conf), `redis-server` doesn’t daemonize by default, which means that `Type=forking` is definitely incorrect. `Type=notify` seems to be the best option, since redis supports explicit readiness notification for systemd; however, that requires the `supervised` option, which is also apparently not enabled by default. So you probably want to add `--supervised systemd` to the `ExecStart=` directive.

Comment: Doesn't forking is better according the systemd manual doc , my
redis.conf has  
supervised systemd  not has ExecStart= (I can't search the word on redis.conf),what is the ExecStart meaing and write to what place ? Any /tmp like log use?

Comment: No, `Type=forking` is definitely not “better”, I don’t know where you got that idea (my version of the `systemd.exec` manpage doesn’t say anything like that). The `ExecStart=` directive is in the unit file (`/etc/systemd/system/redis.service`), not in the redis config file.

Comment: Oh, I see. I already had 'supervised' and 'execstart' on my redis.conf and redis.service. But the forking  still got the error result when systemctl start redis. So I give up the forking type. Thanks for your reply~